# Call Apex method to iterate the value in a lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, template

Trying to iterate the value in lightning vertical tab, data is showing empty.

Can anyone please help me what's wrong in the below code.

**HTML:**

```
 <lightning-vertical-navigation compact>
                                <div class="slds-p-left_x-large">
                                    <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
                                        <template  for:each={wiredStudentDataRefresh.data} for:item="getstudents"
                                            for:index="index">
                                            <lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon  key={studentdata.Id} 
                                            label={wiredStudentDataRefresh.FirstName} icon-name="utility:groups">
                                        </lightning-vertical-navigation-item-icon>

                                        </template>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </lightning-vertical-navigation>
```

**JS:**

```
 @track sturenterror;
@track studentdata;

 @wire(getStudentdetails, { enrollmentName: "$recordId" })
getstudents(response) {
this.wiredStudentDataRefresh = response;
const studentData = response.data;
const studentError = response.error;
if (studentData) {
  this.studentdata = studentData;
} else if (studentError) {
  this.sturenterror = studentError;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of calling refreshApex where you do?

Comment: I have a input fields  in this form, on save this will show the data in data table.

Comment: Note the typo in "this.sturenterror". Also note that you try to get FirstName from the wrong object, by the look of it.

Comment: (That doesn't explain why you clear the cache and re-invoke the wire as soon as you get a response back from the wire)

Comment: oops, Soory Phil W, It was my bad. Removed the code